# mysql query execute multiple time

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have mysqli query that insert to database but when i click trigger it, it insert twice,inserting a dumb data and the real data below is my code

```
<?php
$usernme = ($_POST['testify']);

$id = $_SESSION['XD'];

$ac = 1;
$ti = time();


$queryNewPlege = "INSERT INTO posts (text, timeline_id, active, time) 
      VALUES ('$usernme', '$id', '$ac', '$ti')";

if (mysqli_query($dbhandle, $queryNewPlege)) {

    $getLastInsertID = mysqli_insert_id($dbhandle);

    $upQuery = "UPDATE posts SET post_id =$getLastInsertID WHERE id=$getLastInsertID";
    mysqli_query($dbhandle, $upQuery);
} {

}
?>
```

it work fine but insert twice,first a dumb data and secondly the real data,been looking at it for some time now but still could not fined the error, please any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what smart thing does the update statement?

Comment: you are not upload full code

Comment: Which query execute twice? Also, please learn about SQL injection and how to prevent them. Always use prepared statements for queries with user inputs, your code is really vulnerable right now. For more information visit http://bobby-tables.com

Comment: @AnandPandey indeed he is not **upload full code** he is _Dero3376_

Comment: the second query doesn't make sense

Comment: @madalinivascu : yes i said to him only not you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sir you may try following code;`e`
 `$queryNewPlege = "INSERT INTO posts (text, timeline_id, active, time) 
  VALUES ('$usernme', '$id', '$ac', '$ti')";'`

```
$vars=mysqli_query($dbhandle,$queryNewPlege);  if(!$vars){

  }else{ $getLastInsertID = mysqli_insert_id($dbhandle);

  $upQuery = "UPDATE posts SET post_id =$getLastInsertID WHERE id=$getLastInsertID";
   mysqli_query($dbhandle, $upQuery); } `
```

Comment: fix it already did not start the statement with if (isset($_POST['arribute'])), so when ever i refresh the page the code runs. thanks for your answer really appreciate